# App crashes after logging in using facebook connect

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have setup my application key and secret as well as added the facebook connect button to my view. When I select the button and login within the app, it crashes with the following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CategoryQuoteViewController session:didLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d10800'

I have no idea what this is and cant find anything on the facebook wiki.

Comment: Post the code that produces that error please. Looks like you are calling a method that does not exist.

Comment: Add it as an answer so you can keep your 100% :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The - (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid delegate method needed to be added.